# Is Little-Endianness a byte order or a bit order in the x86 architecture?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, endianness

The title says it all. I want to know whether an x86 instruction that reads data from memory, translates its **bytes** or its **bits** to the Little-Endian order. For example if we have the following data at address 0 (in binary) (written here in RAW format, sequential):

00110010 01010100

And we read it the following way:

```
mov ax, word [0]
```

What will `AX` contain - "01010100 00110010" or "00101010 01001100"? Or translated into unsigned integer in decimal - "21554" or "10828"?
I suppose that the x86 integer instructions will interpret the register sequential binary data as a Big-Endian binary number, the same endianness as Arabic numbers are written.

Comment: endianness is generally at the multi-byte level. you shouldn't have to worry about bit-ordering in a single byte.

Comment: I'm using a 2 byte data or one "word" as you should have noted before commenting but thanks for the answer ("endianness is generally at the multi-byte level") anyway.

Comment: The processor both reads and writes those bits, the order never matters.  While they could never agree about which side of the egg matters most, programmers do universally write the most significant bit on the left.

Comment: -1 for **zero** research effort shown

Comment: @xmojmr - I think its a fair question for someone less experienced. As far as I know, he would only see the effects of endian-ness if he was viewing *both* registers and memory. He may not know how to do it.

Comment: @jww I think the question shows zero research effort (though it can be useful). Google: "x86 endian" gives me as 1st link [Wikipedia: Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_and_hardware) which says "_...The Intel x86 and x86-64 series of processors use the little-endian format, and for this reason, the little-endian format is also known as the Intel convention_...". Showing a research effort (also by someone less experienced) is listed as 1st point ("Search, and research") in [Help Center > How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[1.3.1 Bit and Byte Order](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)
x86 is little-endian.
In illustrations of data structures in memory, smaller addresses appear toward the bottom of the figure; addresses increase toward the top. Bit positions are numbered from right to left. The numerical value of a set bit is equal to two raised to the power of the bit position. IA-32 processors are “little endian” machines; this means the bytes of
a word are numbered starting from the least significant byte. Figure 1-1 illustrates these conventions.

[image]

The terms endian and endianness refer to the convention used to interpret the bytes making up a data word when those bytes are stored in computer memory. In computing, memory commonly stores binary data by organizing it into 8-bit units called bytes. When reading or writing a data word consisting of multiple such units, the order of the bytes stored in memory determines the interpretation of the data word.

Each byte of data in memory has its own address. Big-endian systems store the most significant byte of a word in the smallest address and the least significant byte is stored in the largest address (also see Most significant bit). Little-endian systems, in contrast, store the least significant byte in the smallest address.

The illustration to the right shows an example using the data word "0A 0B 0C 0D" (a set of 4 bytes written out using left-to-right positional, hexadecimal notation) and the four memory locations with addresses a, a+1, a+2 and a+3; then, in big-endian systems, byte 0A is stored in a, 0B in a+1, 0C in a+2 and 0D in a+3. In little-endian systems, the order is reversed with 0D stored in memory address a, 0C in a+1, 0B in a+2, and 0A in a+3.

[image]
[image]

So, as you can see *endianness* is always about **bytes** order not bits.

Comment: Its a nice graphic but you did not answer his question. Here it is again: *"Is Little-Endian a byte or bit order in x86 architecture?"*.

Comment: `Little-Endian` and `Big-Endian` specify order in which _bytes_ are stored in memory for 2-, 4- or 8- byte values. Bits in byte are always in order from MSB (Most Significant Bit) on the left to LSB (Least significant bit) on the right, indexed from right to left.

x86 is `Little-Endian`

Answer (score 20):

AFAIK, endianness is *never* a bit order, it is always a byte order, no matter for which processor.

The lowest bit is always considered to be at the "right" side and the highest at the "left" side of an integral value (be it a 1, 2, 4, or 8 byte value), so shifts or rotations to the "right" always go toward the lowest bit and to the "left" always toward the highest bit. This is independent of endianness.

The x86 is little endian, meaning that the lowest byte comes first (i.e. at the lowest address). This means that the bytes `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x03` and `0x04`, in that order, can just as well be seen as the 32 bit value `0x04030201`, two 16 bit values of `0x0201` and `0x0403` or 4 single bytes (assuming that bytes are *octets*, i.e. 8 bit values -- there are systems where bytes have other bit sizes, but not the x86).

Comment: Related: vector byte-shifts (`pslldq`) and element indexing (`pshufd`/`shufps`/`pblend`...) treat vector registers the same way as bit-shifts treat the bits in an integer register.  So in comments, it's better (but harder to type) to keep track of which elements are where with notation like `// [ d c b a ]`.  This is why `_mm_set_epi32(d, c, b, a);` takes its args in the opposite order from `int arr = {a, b, c, d};`

Comment: Incidentally, bit order endianness does matter sometimes but x86 arch doesn't have the hardware that would let you observe it because it doesn't have any buses narrower than a byte.

Comment: There is no bit order endianness, AFAIK. At least not at the software level. I know of no processor where a bit **shifted** left will turn up in a "lower" position or a bit shifted right in a "higher" position.

Comment: PPC numbers the bits backwards (or at least they used to), so a left shift moves a bit from position 1 to position 0.  8051 is a bit-addressable architecture, and its endianness is defined down to the bit level (and it's little-endian even at the bit level).

Comment: So 1 << 3 would not result in 8? I wouldn't want to write software in which that isn't true. After all, left and right are just arbitrary conventions, and I would consider "left" as "towards the higher bit", regardless of the underlying hardware.

Comment: PowerPC numbers bits with MSB=0, but that only matters when encoding immediates for instructions like [`rlwinm`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=is-rlwinm-rlinm-rotate-left-word-immediate-then-mask-instruction) that generates a mask given low and high bit-numbers.  So the immediate you need depends on whether it's a 32 or 64-bit PowerPC! But yes, there are limits to IBM's insanity. https://godbolt.org/z/EE87PT3e3 shows that PowerPC still uses `sldi %r3,%r3, 3` to multiply a ppc double-word (64-bit) by 8.  But `rldic %r3,%r3,3,32` to shift and zero-extend a 32-bit type.

Answer (score 3):

Binary is a bit tedious, so I translated it to hex; hope that's okay.

The answer to your question, in this case, is that you will get 21,554 (in decimal).

Here is how you can ascertain this on your own...

First, place those two bytes in memory somewhere, with the `Equ $`

```
Some_16_Bit_Value   Equ         $
                    Db          032h
                    Db          054h
```

Okay, now with that in your `.Data` segment, put something like this in your `.Code` segment..

```
        Mov         Ax, Word Ptr [Some_16_Bit_Value]        ;See what you get
```

The assembler will generate a complete instruction for you, like this...

```
        mov         ax,word ptr [Some_16_Bit_Value (13FE9A002h)]
```

Open a debug window and view that memory location (i.e., `13FE9A002h`)

There you will see the first two bytes are: `32 54`  (Those are hex, which is what just about everybody uses)

Step into that `mov` instruction

You will see that `AX` will then contain `5432` (in hex, which is your decimal 21,554)

Comment: Its a nice answer but you did not answer his question. Here it is again: *"Is Little-Endian a byte or bit order in x86 architecture?"*.

Comment: @jww "*...you did not answer his question. Here it is again:...*" I'll have to get better, as this is what I read in the original post, "*...What will 'ax' contain ...in decimal - "21554" or "10828"?...*"